# imread is not found in misc module

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use misc.imsave('lena.png', l) and it always tells me that imsave is not found. I read and search for answers and still no clue.

I imported both scipy and PIL module.

```
>>> import scipy
>>> from scipy import misc
>>> l = misc.lena()
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> misc.imsave('lena.png', l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#53>", line 1, in <module>
  misc.imsave('lena.png', l)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imsave'
```

Any suggestions how to make it work?

Comment: What version of scipy do you have installed?  How did you install it?

Comment: I installed scipy from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy.   I installed "scipy-0.12.0.win32-py3.3.‌exe". I got PIL from the same location too (Pillow-2.1.0.win32-py3.3.‌exe).

Comment: I'm using Linux, so I don't get exactly the same error, but I do get an error.  I don't get the error if I don't run `from PIL import Image` before calling `misc.imsave(...)`.  Could you try it again without that import?

Comment: yes. ｔｈｉｓ　ｔｉｍｅ　Ｉ　ｓａｖｅｄ　ｔｈｅ　ｉｍａｇｅ　ｗｉｔｈｏｕｔ　ｅｒｒｏｒ．　ｉｔ　ｉｓ　ｗｉｅｒｄ　ｔｏ　ｍｅ as I searched for answers and some thread suggested using PIL and this site noted that: misc.imsave('lena.png', l) # uses the Image module (PIL) (http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/image_processing/)

Comment: how can I mark this as resolved question? Thank you Warren for helping me trouble shoot my problem.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: I don't get an error using `imsave`. The error that I got was because of a typo.

Comment: The problem you reported sounds like a bug, possibly related to this one: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1899.  Could you create a new issue for this on the scipy github site? (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing this line:

```
from PIL import Image
```

There have been problems with PIL imports in the past (e.g. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1899).  Perhaps the problem is not completely fixed.